# Cannot initialize jssor slider if it's loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My page uses jQuery's .load() to ajax in the html code for the jssor slider. 
To test my code I've created another identical page that already has the code for the slider and does not do an ajax call.

Just to make sure my page is ready, I've put a button that fires the function that initializes the jssor slider on both examples. Once the Ajax call is made the two pages are identical and when I click the button only the static page initializes the slider.

What am I missing here? Any ideas?

Comment: You are probably trying to initialize something before the Ajax request returned. Hard to say without seeing any code.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the slider on the jquery.load callback.

```
$("#element").load("path/to/load",function(){
    //initialize here
});
```